# Hirsch length of a product of subgroups

Tags: group-theory

A group $G$ is **polycyclic-by-finite** if it admits a subnormal series
$$G = G_0 \trianglerighteq G_1 \trianglerighteq \cdots \trianglerighteq G_m = 1$$
where each quotient $G_i/G_{i+1}$ is either finite or infinite cyclic. The number of infinite cyclic factors is called the **Hirsch length** of $G$:
$$h(G) := |\{i\in \{0,\ldots,m-1\} : [G_i:G_{i+1}]=\infty\}|.$$
This is actually independent of the choice of subnormal series, so it is an invariant of $G$. If $G$ is polycyclic-by-finite, it's not hard to show that all subgroups/quotients are too, and the Hirsch length satisfies
$$h(G/N) = h(G) - h(N) \tag{$*$}$$
for any $N\trianglelefteq G$.

Below, recall that if $A,B\leq G$, we let $AB$ denote the subgroup *generated* by products $ab$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.
$$AB := \langle ab : a\in A, b\in B \rangle.$$

> **Problem.** Show that $h(AB)=h(A)+h(B)-h(A\cap B)$.

I can prove this if $A$ is *normal* in $G$. In this case, the Second Isomorphism Theorem gives $AB/A\simeq B/(A\cap B)$, so we use formula $(*)$ to calculate
$$h(AB) - h(A) = h(B) - h(A\cap B)$$
which is equivalent to the desired formula. Same if $B\trianglelefteq G$.

But if neither of $A,B$ are normal in $G$, I'm not sure how to prove this, or if it's even true.

Comment: That's a non-standard way to define $AB$ which is usually just the set of products, and not necessarily a subgroup.

Comment: Because of this, I don't think what you want is true. Take the infinite dihedral group $G=\langle a,b|a^2,b^2\rangle$. This is polycyclic by finite, with Hirsh length 1. Now take $A=\langle a\rangle$ and $B=\langle b\rangle$. We have $G=AB$ (with your nonstandard definition), but each of $A$ and $B$ is finite, so has Hirsh length $0$.

Comment: Also what you write in your first sentence is true but it is not the definition of polycyclic-by-finite, which is a group with a polycyclic subgroup of finite index.

Comment: Thanks for the example! For ideals you usually define $IJ$ as the ideal *generated* by products, but for groups perhaps $\langle AB\rangle$ is more appropriate --- it's odd to me that there's a difference between the notations for rings/groups though. And @DerekHolt, these definitions are readily equivalent, so I didn't think it was harmful to use this one.

Comment: @Ehsaan I would agree with this usually, but there is a more or less universal convention that, for classes of groups ${\mathcal A}$ and ${\mathcal B}$, an ${\mathcal A}$-by${\mathcal B}$ group is one having a normal subgroup $N$ such that $N$ lies in class ${\mathcal A}$ and $G/N$ lies in class ${\mathcal B}$, and it seems a pity to deviate from this definition.

Comment: But ironically you even deviated now: according to your definition, "polycyclic-by-finite" should mean a *normal* polycyclic subgroup, which is not what you originally said. I realize that the normality requirement ends up being superfluous, but my point is that it's OK to use a mild variation on the definition for the sake of brevity/pertinence. Perhaps I should have said "one of the equivalent definitions of polycyclic-by-finite group is ..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the infinite dihedral group $G=\langle a,b|a^2,b^2\rangle$. This is polycyclic by finite, with Hirsch length 1. Now take $A=\langle a\rangle$ and $B=\langle b\rangle$. We have $G=AB$ (with your nonstandard definition, most people would write $\langle AB\rangle$), but each of $A$ and $B$ is finite, so has Hirsch length $0$.